Spring Data Neo4J this.transactionTemplate is null on repository method
I have a Spring Boot project with the Spring Data Neo4J dependency. I have defined a few nodes, a relation and a repository. Now the application starts correctly, but when I send a request to an endpoint that executes a repository method (like save or findById), then it keeps telling me that the transactionTemplate is null. I am guessing this is a configuration issue, but I haven't been able to find any helpful information online.
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = {"api.data.neo4j"})
public class AgendaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AgendaApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Data
@Node("Agenda")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AgendaNode {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
}

public interface AgendaRepository extends Neo4jRepository<AgendaNode, Long> {
}

AgendaNode agendaNode = new AgendaNode(1);
agendaRepository.save(agendaNode); // This is where it causes the error

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallback)" because "this.transactionTemplate" is null] with root cause
2024-06-17 11:41:39 
2024-06-17 11:41:39 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallback)" because "this.transactionTemplate" is null
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:382) ~[spring-data-neo4j-7.3.0.jar:7.3.0]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.SimpleNeo4jRepository.save(SimpleNeo4jRepository.java:120) ~[spring-data-neo4j-7.3.0.jar:7.3.0]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392) ~[spring-tx-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy137.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at application.api.endpoints.restful.test.TestService.test(TestService.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at application.api.endpoints.restful.test.TestController.test(TestController.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
2024-06-17 11:41:39     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

I tried the AgendaApplication versions below, but they all kept giving me the issue that this.transactionTemplate is null.
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = {"api.data.neo4j"})
public class AgendaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AgendaApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = {"api.data.neo4j"})
public class AgendaApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AgendaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    }
}

I also tried using the ReactiveNeo4jRepository instead of the Neo4jRepository and I tried overwriting the save method in the repository, but that didn't work either.
Can anyone help resolve my issue?

Please add the full stacktrace instead of a snippet.

Thanks for the suggestion @M.Deinum, I have added the entire stacktrace.

I have the same issue

I've encountered the same problem today. This works for me:

Add a configuration file Neo4jConfig in your project:

package dev.bookstore.creeper.demo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConfig {

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager(org.neo4j.driver.Driver driver) {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(driver);
    }
}


Then add a @EnableTransactionManagement annotation in main SpringApplication file, just as you mentioned above:


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class OnlineBookstoreBackendApplication {
  // xxx
}

Now you may read and write data using Neo4jRepository.
